# Victory chart, stacked bar one inside other

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

[image]

How to implement something like this in victory-native?

Answer (score 1):

with a VictoryGroup that surrounds three VictoryBars, each with a different barWidth

```
<VictoryGroup>
  <VictoryBar barWidth={30} />
  <VictoryBar barWidth={20} />
  <VictoryBar barWidth={10} />
</VictoryGroup>
```